Invalid range in '{}' in regular expression
i'm trying make parser to my project, however when I'm running it I got Invalid range in '{}' in regular expression.
I don't really know what's wrong in this code. I'm beginner in Regular Expresions so I can misunderstand them.
    const string& code;
    const regex functionPattern(R"((\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{)");
    const regex variablePattern(R"((\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*(?:=\s*([^;]+))?\s*;)");

    smatch matches;

    string::const_iterator searchStart(code.cbegin());

    cout << "Functions:" << endl;
    
    while (regex_search(searchStart, code.cend(), matches, functionPattern)) {
        cout << "Function: " << matches[1] << endl;
        cout << "Function name: " << matches[2] << endl;
        cout << "Arguments: " << matches[3] << endl;

        searchStart = matches.suffix().first;
    }

    searchStart = code.cbegin();

    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Variables:" << endl;

    while (regex_search(searchStart, code.cend(), matches, variablePattern)) {
        cout << "Variable: " << matches[1] << endl;
        cout << "Variable name: " << matches[2] << endl;
        if (matches[3].matched) {
            cout << "Initial value: " << matches[3] << endl;
        }

        searchStart = matches.suffix().first;
    }

Here is example code which I want to parse:
    int a = 5;
    int b = 8;

    void Function(int a, int b) {
    
    }

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.
Greetings.

Escape the { char in the regex

First of all I recommend you try out your regular expression on something like https://regex101.com. Then don't try to do too much at once, start with the simplest code possible, basically an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. Once it builds, test. Only when all tests passes, you continue to add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Then when you have a problem, it becomes very easy to isolate it and understanding what it might be, and of course to solve it.

{ in a regular expression is a special character, you need to escape it \{, just like you do with (.

FWIW, C++ is too complicated to parse with a regex in general.  Simple code works but once you start adding in all the crazy that C++ allows it gets much harder.

I recommend using a parser to parse.  I like Boost Spirit X3 (v3.10 is the latest) parser.  If you're trying to write your own programming language, I recommend llvm Kaleidoscope tutorial.
